# Problem with SQL (Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar)

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

I have a problem with the sintax below where i tried to union two DEs where the Month is the Primary Key. 
All Data Extension in the case have the fiedls type like Text.

**ERROR:  Query failed during execution. Error: Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'July' to data type int.**

```
select
Count(*) as [Users],
[Month] as [Month]
FROM [DE_1]
GROUP BY [Month]
UNION
Select 
[Month] as [Month],
Send as [Sends_Totally]
from [DE_2]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your union the fields have to be in the same order, Since `users` is a count(int) in the first query and `Month` is a nvarchar, it can't convert the value 'July' to an INT.

A [union](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp) requires the same number of fields with the same field type  in the same order

> Each SELECT statement within UNION must have the same number of columns
>
> The columns must also have similar data types
>
> The columns in each SELECT statement must also be in the same order

**Updated**

I don't think your use case should be done with a Union but a join

```
SELECT
Count(*) as [Users],
a.[Month],
b.[Sends_Totally]
FROM [DE_1] a
JOIN [DE_2] b on a.Month = b.Month
GROUP BY [Month]
```

Comment: I have a problem with this, @EazyE.

 Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'DE_3'. The duplicate key value is (July).

Comment: @JoaoMarano can both select queries return the value of July?

Comment: Yes, but the 'month' field is primary key'. I want the DE_2 just update the field Sends_Totally in one SQL.

Comment: I think you shouldn't use a UNION but a JOIN, I've updated my answer

Comment: So Thanks, @EazyE